# No puedo importar dos clases Java

Tags: java

El tema es que en mi clase Principal.java , no me detecta dos clases ( Analex y Anasint) , no sé a que se debe ser , adjunto pantallazo para que sea muestre mejor. He probado con import Analex.java por ejemplo , pero no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error "cannot resolver symbol Analex"

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para cambiar la imagen por el texto del código y agregar el mensaje completo del error que estás teniendo.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el nombre del paquete que tienen dichas clases? (`package`).

Comment: "cannot resolver symbol Analex" , es el error que me sale

Comment: Y antlr lo  he importado como .jar

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el `package` de las clases java que quieres importar? Por cierto, buscando referencias sobre ANTLR, he encontrado este ejercicio que parece que es lo que intentas hacer: [http://lsiweb.lsi.us.es/docencia/get.php?id=9445](http://lsiweb.lsi.us.es/docencia/get.php?id=9445). Toda información que facilites en tu pregunta es información que ayudará a responder tu duda.

Comment: De hecho lo he copiado de ahí , pero no funcional por los imports que te he comentado. Acabo de adjuntar un pantallazo en la pregunta sobre la estructura

Comment: Sigo sin conocer el `package` de las clases java que quieres importar. Sin esa información no se sabe qué ruta agregar a un `import`. Matando moscas a cañonazos, podrías probar a usar `import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;` y `import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;`. Si eso te funciona significa que el paquete es `org.antlr.v4.runtime` y que podrías usar `import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Analex;` y `import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Anasint;`.

Comment: Es que no entiendo muy bien IntelliJ , que yo sepa no lo he metido en ningún package. Las clases están dentro de gen/ , que es la carpeta que se genera al compilar los archivos .g4

Comment: Basta con abrir uno de esos archivos generados para poder obtener la información que te solicito. Un archivo java es un archivo java, haya sido generado por InteliJ o por una persona humana. Mientras tanto, ¿podrías hacer las pruebas que te sugerí en el comentario anterior?

Comment: Con lo que me has dicho lo he probado , pero sale el mismo error. Te adjunto la cabecera de la clase Analex también , parece que no está en ningun package..

Comment: // Generated from C:/Users/Juan/IdeaProjects/p1/src\Analex.g4 by ANTLR 4.8
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Token;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa.DFA;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.*;

@SuppressWarnings({"all", "warnings", "unchecked", "unused", "cast"})
public class Analex extends Lexer {

Comment: Deberías agregar esta información a tu pregunta usando el enlace de [editar pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/397683/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Modifica la configuración de la estructura del proyecto en `Project Structure`. En la pestaña `Modules` de la ventana que te salga, ve a `Sources`, haz click en la carpeta `gen` y márcala como `Sources`.